# Installed cocos2d-objc but it says cocos2d swift

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have application which uses cocos2d, and it worked fine before.

I updated cocos2d-obj in myapp project.

After that, my application stop after splash screen.

What the mysterious point is I surely installed the cocos2d-objc

from [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc), but there are some messages in log that say 'cocos2D-Swift'....??

I had some misunderstanding...??

error  log below

```
cocos2d: Cocos2D-Swift version 3.4.3-develop
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: 9.2 (0x09020000)
cocos2d: 64 bit runtime
cocos2d: Multi-threaded rendering: 0
cocos2d: OpenGL Rendering enabled.cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:    Apple Inc.
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER:  Apple Software Renderer
cocos2d: GL_VERSION:   OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-12.0.40
cocos2d: GLSL_VERSION: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
cocos2d: CCGraphicsBufferClass: CCGraphicsBufferGLUnsynchronized
cocos2d: CCGraphicsBufferBindingsClass: CCGraphicsBufferBindingsGL
cocos2d: CCRenderCommandDrawClass: CCRenderCommandDrawGL
2016-02-20 06:08:59.312 myapp[2859:886706] cocos2d: viewDidLoad
cocos2d: Cocos2D-Swift version 3.4.3-develop
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: 9.2 (0x09020000)
cocos2d: 64 bit runtime
cocos2d: Multi-threaded rendering: 0
cocos2d: OpenGL Rendering enabled.cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:    Apple Inc.
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER:  Apple Software Renderer
cocos2d: GL_VERSION:   OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-12.0.40
cocos2d: GLSL_VERSION: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
cocos2d: CCGraphicsBufferClass: CCGraphicsBufferGLUnsynchronized
cocos2d: CCGraphicsBufferBindingsClass: CCGraphicsBufferBindingsGL
cocos2d: CCRenderCommandDrawClass: CCRenderCommandDrawGL
2016-02-20 06:09:00.056 myapp[2859:886706] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 60.00
2016-02-20 06:09:00.060 myapp[2859:886706] cocos2d: surface size: 960x1704
(lldb)
```

error happens here

```
// override default logic
- (void)runWithScene:(CCScene*) scene
{
    NSAssert( scene != nil, @"Argument must be non-nil");
    NSAssert(_runningScene == nil, @"This command can only be used to start the CCDirector. There is already a scene present.");

    [self pushScene:scene];

    NSThread *thread = [self runningThread];

// error happned here.
    [self performSelector:@selector(drawScene) onThread:thread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
       Thred 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2D-Swift was just a marketing name. Apportable company which sponsored us back in the day called it that way to attract more people.

Now when Apportable bankrupted, we changed the name back to Cocos2D-ObjC. Even though it is full Swift enabled, it has no Swift code internally.

Update to last stable version (3.4.0) or to the newest 3.5-RC which is due to be released soon.

Comment: I understood. I have developped my application with sprite builder/Apportable. I am surprised that Apportable was bankrupted. I will try Cocos-2D without apportable/spritebuilder support.

Comment: We still support sprite builder, but without Apportable's Android plugin